# Appending specific integers to nested lists - Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested, append

I have a nested list, `A = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 7], [4, 8, 9]]`. I want to add the numbers `1, 2, 3` in `list A` to be `A = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [5, 2, 7, 2], [4, 8, 9, 3]]` and so on (this is just a shorter version). I tried the same using the code I wrote:

```
i = 0
j = 0
#number_nests = number of nested lists
for i in range(0, number_nests):
    for j in A:
        j.append(i)

print(A)
```

This is the output which I am getting, since I am a newbie, I am a little stuck:
`[[1, 90, 150, 0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 100, 200, 0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 105, 145, 0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 110, 190, 0, 1, 2, 3]]`. I am trying to do it without numpy.

Comment: no need of `range(0, number_nests)`, `0` is default `start` in `range`.So simply `range(number_nests)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 7], [4, 8, 9]]
i=1
for val in A:
    val.append(i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply iterate over the outer list along with the indexes, using `enumerate`:

```
for i, elem_list in enumerate(A, start=1):
    elem_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function with start parameter as `1` to get current index.

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 7], [4, 8, 9]]

print([val+[i] for i, val in enumerate(A, 1)])
```

---

Using [map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) built-in function

In python 2.x

```
print map(lambda x,y: x+[y],  A, range(1, len(A)+1))
```

In python 3.x

```
print(list(map(lambda x,y: x+[y], A, range(1, len(A)+1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 7], [4, 8, 9]]
B = [1, 2, 3]
print [A[i]+[B[i]] for i in range(len(A))]
#Output[[1, 2, 3, 1], [5, 2, 7, 2], [4, 8, 9, 3]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need one loop to add one number to each list in `A`:

```
for i in range(1, len(A)+1):
    A[i].append(i)
```

Note: the range should start at 1